# setup network/internet connection to install xorg

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, arch-linux

I have installed ArchLinux (everything by default) in VMware. I want to connetct to the internet so I can install xorg and other packages. Here is what I tryed:

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.23/255.255.255.0 dev eth0
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
dhcpcd eth0
```

After this, I try to ping google:

```
ping -c 3 www.google.com
```

and all packages are lost. Anyone can tell me what i've done wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set the VM Network Adapter to NAT
- dhcpcd eth0 (pops an error: /usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/30-hostname: line 9: hostname: command not found dhcpcd[666]: forked to background, child pid 687)

now pinging goole works just fine